# LibreOffice Calc display formula reference cell

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

When i select the cell with formula, there will show the related cell with highlight in old version(new version don't have it). What is the setting in new version ?
[image]

Comment: What version and operating system?  It would help to show a screen capture of the behavior in the new version.

Comment: Windows 8.1 64bit, LibreOffice 5.4.3.2 x64, the picture in above is old version, but new version don't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> View* and check the box *Show references in color.*

Comment: In new version, already checked the box "Show references in color", but can't work

Comment: I find the solution is double click on the formula cell, the function will appear.